# Jquery Transversing - Having Issues Traveling up the tree

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey im drawing some blanks here hope you can help :)
here is my code clip

```
<ul id="add_col">
  <li id="row_1"> <a onclick="add_row('container_1_1','','row_1','',0)" href="javascript:void(0);" class="aadd" style="display: none;">+</a>&nbsp;
<div id="container_1_1" class="drop-container ui-droppable"></div>
<ul id="dr2761">
  <li id="row_1"><a onclick="add_row('container_1_2','rem2761','row_1','','')" href="javascript:void(0);" id="rem2761" class="aadd" style="display: inline;">+</a> <a onclick="tremove('2761','row','row_1')" href="javascript:void(0);" class="arem">-</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div id="container_1_2" class="drop-container ui-droppable"><span id="key_3" class="movable ui-draggable">ricky1</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Im in `div container_1_2` and im trying to transverse up to `div container_1_1`
I tried multiple `parent()` calls.. `prev()`.. `find()` combinations etc.. how
can I reach the parent ancestor `div`?

Thanks for your help
Ricky

Comment: The problem is that `container_1_1` is not an ancestor of `container_1_2`. Are you sure your HTML is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#container_1_2').closest('ul').prev();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2ADNd/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container_1_2').closest('ul').prev();
```

I think it should be something like this. The `#` make you get the element by Id, and get the closest `ul` element, previous itself

Comment: There's no closest DIV in his HTML, the element he wants to traverse up to is UL.